# Getting NaN with Stopwatch app React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was trying to implement Stopwatch app with React. Everything is implemented and looks like it is working right now. But, when I clicked stop button and then start button again, the result of NaN is shown on the page. Is there any idea to fix this issue?

I think that I should change the data type from String to Number at some points. I tried to use Number() to fix the issue, but it didn't work.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Stopwatch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      startTime: 0,
      elapsedTime: 0,
      timerId: null,
      isRunning: false,
      timeToAdd: 0
    };
  }

  updateTimerText = () => {
    const m = Math.floor(this.state.elapsedTime / 60000);
    const s = Math.floor((this.state.elapsedTime % 60000) / 1000);

    this.setState({
      elapsedTime: m + ":" + s
    });
  };

  countUp = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerId: setTimeout(() => {
        // this.state.elapsedTime = Date.now() - this.state.startTime;
        this.setState({
          elapsedTime: Date.now() - this.state.startTime + this.state.timeToAdd
        });
        this.updateTimerText();
        this.countUp();
      }, 100)
    });

    this.state.timerId;
  };

  handleStart = () => {
    if (this.state.isRunning === true) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      isRunning: true
    });
    this.setState({
      startTime: Date.now()
    });
    this.countUp();
  };

  handleStop = () => {
    if (this.state.isRunning === false) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      isRunning: false
    });
    this.setState({
      timeToAdd: this.timeToAdd + (Date.now() - this.state.startTime)
    });
    clearTimeout(this.state.timerId);
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    if (this.state.isRunning === true) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      elapsedTime: 0
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.elapsedTime}</div>

        <button onClick={this.handleStart}>Start</button>

        <button onClick={this.handleStop}>Stop</button>

        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<Stopwatch />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: `elapsedTime: m + ":" + s` is a string, but elsewhere this state property is treated as a number. In `handleStop` there is `timeToAdd: this.timeToAdd` but iz should probably be `this.state.timeToAdd`

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleStop` method you reference `this.timeToAdd`, I think you meant `this.state.timeToAdd`.  Try changing the relevant line to:

```
timeToAdd: this.state.timeToAdd + (Date.now() - this.state.startTime)
```

Instead of overwriting the number in your `elapsedTime` state key with a string, I'd suggest adding a new key... something like `elapsedTimeFormatted`.  You can set this state key to the string you want to render in your `updateTimerText` method, and then reference it instead of `elapsedTime` in your render method.

For reference, when trying to get a number from a string, you probably want `parseInt`.  More information here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is just a small forgotten state access in `handleStop`:

```
this.setState({
    timeToAdd: this.timeToAdd + (Date.now() - this.state.startTime)
});
```

should be

```
this.setState({
    timeToAdd: this.state.timeToAdd + (Date.now() - this.state.startTime)
});
```

On another note, after making this change, resetting doesn't actually reset the stopwatch because timeToAdd is left unchanged. Not sure if this is the intended behavior, but if it isn't then reset needs

```
this.setState({
    elapsedTime: 0,
    timeToAdd: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking care of my question!
The reason I couldn't get what I expected is that I just forgot to use state access in `handleStop`

And, another found error is in `handleReset`. I needed to reset timeToAdd.